# Escaping double quotes inside a json text that is built with double quotes (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, escaping

I have a large dataframe and one column stores json-dictionary type values, such as:

```
{"comment": "This is a "Great" restaurant"}
```

The problem is that there are un-escaped double quotes inside the dictionary. Is there a handy way to escape these quotes, instead of manually adding `\` to each of them (got more than 4000 rows)? Any ideas?

Comment: This might be an XY problem. If you do ``print( json.dumps({ "this": 'this "is" great!' }) )`` you will see that the output is already escaped: ``{"this": "this \"is\" great!"}``. Thus you should probably ask yourself why there's an invalid JSON string in the first place.

Comment: mpf82, has a very good point here. i would not warry about the reading of the data, i will rather ensure that there is no way invalid json can end up in the database, and if so, i will fix it with a sql query rather than to try and excape the quotes on read time. reason for fixing it with sql, all database engines are super optimized whem it comes to changing data in tables, so it will be millions of times faster than looping over every item and escaping the quotes

Comment: @mpf82 good feedback. It is true that some records had mal json format, and I had to correct them manually! Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: and @diegeelvis_SA see my comment above!